# Measure or remove space above letters

Tags: html, css

When using h1 it creates an empty space above the letters, not a margin nor padding. (see picture)

I want the text to be as far from the side as it is from the top. I can do this by adding a left padding on the body, but I don't know how much I should make this padding since the spacing at the top is based on the h1 size.

How would I solve this?

[image: The problem]

Comment: check `line-height`

Comment: You can find default settings for h1 here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp

Comment: Share your markup and css code please.

Comment: That space is there *on purpose* to keep the lines separate, You'll probably find it's built into the glyphs.

Comment: This is practically a headache if you ask me, to do such thing you'll need to manipulate the `lineHeight` property, Now by default it's set to `normal` which roughly 1.2 (depends on the user agent), it also differs from a font to another.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Thank you! I ended up leaving it as it is since it never did turn out right :P I didn't know about lineHeight until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using CSS. Here is sample code for it:

```
h1 { 
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.21em;
    margin-bottom: 0.67em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Yes but by default h1 will give a spacing. Try this: h1{margin:0;}